# Setting up DRBD on an active MySQL server

Tags: mysql, replication, storage

When it comes to setting up DRBD and MySQL, is the following possible?

- Set up DRBD on an active MySQL server
- Set up DRBD with no downtime allowed

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to do either one.

Once you create `/dev/drbd0` on both DB Servers, you have to mount the DRBD Primary on a folder. That folder cannot have anything with active file handles. The protocol I use is:

```
drbdadm primary drbd0
mount /dev/drbd0 /var/lib/mysql
service mysql start
```

You want DRBD to house MySQL Data. Here is what you must do instead

```
service mysql stop
mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql_old
mkdir /var/lib/mysql
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
drbdadm primary drbd0
mount /dev/drbd0 /var/lib/mysql
cp -R /var/lib/mysql_old /var/lib/mysql
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
service mysql start
```

As shown, stopping mysqld is mandatory.

## UPDATE 2013-03-16 21:46 EDT

There is something incredibly tough you can try

- Given ServerDB1 with MySQL Running
- Given ServerDB2 to introduce as DRBD partner

## STEP 01) Setup DRBD on Separate ServerDB2

As I mentioned earlier, you can house mysql on a DRBD mount.

## STEP 02) Setup MySQL Replication

Huh ??? How did MySQL Replication enter the picture

- You need to mysqldump everything in ServerDB1
- Load the mysqldump into MySQL running in ServerDB2
- Setup Replication so all changes are migrated since loading of ServerDB2 was done

## STEP 03) Failover Your Application

In simple English, use the IP address of ServerDB2 in your application instead of ServerDB1

You should wait and make sure you have a low peak time to do this failover

## STEP 04) Setup DRBD on Separate ServerDB1

- Setup DRBD
- drbdadm secondary drbd0
- drbdadm coonect drbd0

This is an oversimplified description but you can look up the actual code to sync a DRBD pair

Here is my old DRBD download-and-install script

```
DRBD_VERSION=8.3
DRBD_SUBVERSION=0
DRBD_VERSION_NUMBER=${DRBD_VERSION}.${DRBD_SUBVERSION}
cd
rm -rf drbdinstall
mkdir drbdinstall
cd drbdinstall
wget http://oss.linbit.com/drbd/${DRBD_VERSION}/drbd-${DRBD_VERSION_NUMBER}.tar.gz
gzip -d drbd-${DRBD_VERSION_NUMBER}.tar.gz
tar -xvf drbd-${DRBD_VERSION_NUMBER}.tar
cd drbd-${DRBD_VERSION_NUMBER}
make rpm
rpm -Uvh dist/RPMS/x86_64/drbd-*
```

You can go to www.drbd.org to find out the latest version number and update the aforemtioned script

Give it a Try !!!